# What is the song in this modern painting "Petite"?

Tags: sheet-music

I can't recognise the musical composition on this painting. What is it?

The painting hangs in the modern art museum Brandhorst in Munich. Unfortunately I didn't write the artist or title down, and Google hasn't helped me.

[image: notes and the text "Petite"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Antonin Dvorak OP 90 Dumky Trio](http://216.129.110.22/files/imglnks/usimg/1/13/IMSLP37447-PMLP83172-Dvorak_op.090_Piano_Trio_No.4_Simr.pdf) near the end of the Poco Adagio (D), page 11 second system Violoncello voice.

Comment: Damn. You are good.

Comment: I have unusual [PeachNote](http://www.peachnote.com) Fu